# Ionic/Angular: ngFor does not update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I am trying to make a list of active devices. Keeping this information in instance variable `screens`. Whenever I make the changes with `setTimeOut` it works however if I make the changes in `callback` section it doesn't work.

Here is the code :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";
import { Zeroconf } from '@ionic-native/zeroconf';

@Component({
  selector: "page-home",
  templateUrl: "home.html"
})

export class HomePage {

  screens: Array<{name: any, ip: any}> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private zeroconf: Zeroconf) {


    this.screens.push({
      name: "TEST",
      ip: "123"
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.screens.push({
        name: "TEST2",
        ip: "Test2"
      })
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.screens.push({
        name: "TEST3",
        ip: "Test3"
      })
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.screens.push({
        name: "TEST4",
        ip: "Test4"
      })
    }, 10000);

     this.zeroconf.watch('_http._tcp.', 'local.').subscribe(result => {
      if (result.action == 'added') {
        this.screens.push({              //This is not working
          name: result.service.name,
          ip: result.service.ipv4Addresses
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.screens.push({
            name: result.service.name,
            ip: result.service.ipv4Addresses
          });
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        console.log('service removed', result.service);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

What could be possible cause of this ?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need a BehaviorSubject to update it on regular basis

In you shared service define

```
    listOfScreens: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

    addScreens(newData) {
    this.listOfScreens.next(this.listOfScreens.getValue().concat([newData]));
}
```

and in you component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedService.listofScreens.subscribe(
    screens => this.screens = screens
  )
}

addScreens() {
  let data = {
  name: "TEST",
  ip: "123"
}
  this.sharedService.addScreens(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Added a provider and made everything like you said. Now my problem is that the data will not render again when I add something in the callback.

Comment: Working example is here on this link [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4wjed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts]

Comment: Got it working by updating it manuely with a Interval and setting it own value as next.